# Have you ever seen as i have checked session behaviour in gmail.com ? Please help?

Tags: web, session-state

Yesterday morning i open gmail account in Internet Exlorer second tab. I checked my mail and closed that tab (not browser).

Then at the time of evining i again open second tab of browser and enetr gmail.com, it automatically redirect me at my email account without asking login.

I shocked and i thought i should remain browser open for whole night and today open gmail in second tab , it behave similar means without login screen it redirect in my gmail account.

Then i closed that tab and open another browser session and enter gmail i again surprised that i redirect me login page. At the same time i open second tab of first browser and it automatically redirect me at mail account page.

What i councluded by this behaviour is that might be gmail server keep my browser id at their server so that whenever i eneter gmail.com on second tab of first browser, it automatically redirect me at gmail account. I don't know i am right or not?

Please clear me this concept? What happens with my session at gmail server when i closed my browser tab?

As per my opinion it should automatically logout me but why this doesn't happened?

Answer (score 0):

You probably ticked the option "stay signed in" the last time you logged in. Go back to gmail, click log out, and log in again, making sure that option is not ticked. Close the tab, come back in an hour, and open gmail again. You should be at the login screen this time.

Comment: No No, "stay signed in" option was unchecked. You can also try what i mentioned above.